# where are my source files in IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am facing problems in opening an existing IntelliJ project present on my hard-disk, and connected to a Git repository. When I try opening my project, I only see the data files (that I added manually) in the project structure. I am unable to find the `.idea`, `lib` and `src` folders within my project in the project structure; these files are available on the hard disk at the required locations (auto-generated). Also, I am able to open other IntelliJ projects present in the same root directory properly.

Any idea on how can I can successfully re-open this particular project again?

Comment: Without configuration files your project is missing some important information without looking at your project structure is impossible to reopen this particular projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your project does not contain any modules, and therefore the Project view only shows the immediate contents of the project directory. If you can see .iml files in that directory, you can add them to the project by right-clicking them and selecting the corresponding option in the menu. If not, you'll need to go to the Project Structure dialog and configure the modules manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You were right about the absence of module, so I added the .iml file to the project. But that only adds the .idea folder to the project and the lib and src folders are still missing from the project.

Comment: Then you need to open the Project Structure dialog and add a content root for the .iml file.

Answer (score 2):

Check ignored files and folders in: **File -> Settings -> File Types**

Also check excluded roots in: **File -> Project Structure**

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Checked the excluded roots and ignored files and folders. Not the issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Add -> Import Module -> the pom.xml
```

or

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Add -> Import Module -> .idea -> .idea -> .idea.iml
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Add -> Import Module -> src -> .idea -> src.iml
```